# How to access a 16 bits variable as two 8 bits variables ? And two 8 bits variables as one 16 bit variable

Tags: c++, c++17

I am using C++17.

Let's imagine I have two variables `a` and `b`. These variables are of type `uint8_t`. I would like to be able to access them as uint8_t but also as uint16_t.

For example :

```
#include <memory>


int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 0xFF;
    uint8_t b = 0x00;
    uint16_t ab; // Should be 0xFF00
}
```

I thought that using an array would be a good solution, as the two variable should be next to each other in memory. So I did this :

```cpp
#include <memory>


int main()
{
    uint8_t data[] = {0xFF, 0x00};
    uint8_t * a = data;
    uint8_t * b = data + sizeof(uint8_t);
    uint16_t * ab = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(data);
    
    std::cout << std::hex << (int) *a << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << (int) *b << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << (int) *ab << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ff
0
ff
```

But I would expect :

```
ff
0
ff00
```

Can you explain what I am doing wrong here, any red flags or better ways of doing this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you know the difference between little-endian and big-endian?

Comment: Yes, so it's an endianness problem ? Any solutions ?

Comment: The portable way is to just do arithmetic: `ab = (a << 8) | b;`  And conversely `a = ab >> 8; b = ab & 0xff;`

Comment: try `{0x00, 0xFF};` to see the effect of endianess

Comment: Define what "solution" means to you. What is the specific problem for which a solution is thought?

Comment: My wish here is to have read write access to these variables. I'm writing an emulator and performance is critical. Or is the performance impact or computing the values when getting/setting negligible?

Comment: @TheMackou "Or is the performance impact or computing the values when getting/setting negligible?" --> Yes, it is negligible.  Use [just do arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407696/how-to-access-a-16-bits-variable-as-two-8-bits-variables-and-two-8-bits-variab#comment124459195_70407696) and trust your compiler to optimize for you.

Comment: @TheMackou If the performance impact of computing the values was significant, then the compiler wouldn't compute the values. You can express the code simply and clearly as Nate Eldredge suggested. Then it's the compiler's job to figure out the way to get the best performance when executing that code. Micro-optimizations (the best way to implement simple statements in the platform's native code) are the compiler's job, not yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few other ways to convert between two 8- and one 16-bit value.

But be aware that the results of every solution which directly addresses a single byte in the 16-bit value depend on the byte order of the machine executing it. Intel, for example, uses 'little endian' where the least significant bits are stored first. Other machines may use 'big endian' and store the most significant bits first.

**use bitshift and or to calculate the 16-bit value**

```
const uint8_t a = 0xff;
const uint8_t b = 0x00;
const uint16_t ab = a | (b << 8); // works because b is promoted to int before being shifted
```

**use bitshift and `and` to calculate the 8-bit values**

```
const uint16_t ab = 0xff;
const uint8_t a = ab & 0xff;
const uint8_t b = ab >> 8;
```

**directly address the bytes of the word**

```
uint16_t ab;
auto& a = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&ab)[0];
auto& b = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&ab)[1];
```

**using a union**

*This is explicitly not allowed by the standard* (but also done everywhere)

Declare the following union:

```
union conv
{
    struct {
        uint8_t a, b;
    };
    uint16_t ab;
};
```

You now can use it for combining two 8 bit values into a single 16 bit value:

```
conv c;
c.a = 0xFF;
c.b = 0x00;
std::cout << c.ab << std::endl;
```

On Intel machines this will output 255 (0xff) because Intel uses "little endian" where the least significant bits are stored first. So a is the low byte of ab and b is the high byte.

If you redefine the union as

```
union conv
{
    struct {
        uint8_t b, a;
    };
    uint16_t ab;
};
```

The example above would output 65280 (0xff00) on Intel machines because now b represents the least significat 8 bits of ab and a represents the most significant.

Combining unions and bitfields, you can also access each single bit of the 16-bit value:

```
union bitconv
{
    struct {
        uint16_t
            b0 : 1, b1 : 1, b2 : 1, b3 : 1, b4 : 1, b5 : 1, b6 : 1, b7 : 1,
            b8 : 1, b9 : 1, b10 : 1, b11 : 1, b12 : 1, b13 : 1, b14 : 1, b15 : 1;
    };
    uint16_t word;
};
```

Comment: The bitshift code has the advantage of being defined by the C++ standard. :-) The union code has the disadvantage of explicitly being not allowed (unless you have a compiler extension making it work anyway). And while the bitfields will get you each bit, the order of the bits is also not defined (and known to vary between compilers).

Comment: It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written. [Doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

Comment: You both are absolutly right about this. I never checked the docs for it because it's done everywhere. However, I will modify my answer to include this information and with this in mind, the union should not be the #1 solution. Thank you for teaching me this - I have used unions wrong for nearly 30 years ‍♂️

Comment: I'm glad my question was useful. I consider "use bitshift and or to calculate the 16-bit value" as the good answer.

Answer (score 1):

A portable way with no undefined behaviour to pack 2 `uint8_t` into `uint16_t` and back:

```
int main() {
    uint8_t a = 0xFF;
    uint8_t b = 0x00;

    // from a and b to ab
    uint16_t ab = a * 0x100 + b;

    // from ab to a and b
    a = ab / 0x100 & 0xff;
    b = ab & 0xff;
}
```

---

Note that all methods that rely on casting `uint16_t` to `uint8_t*` only happen to work because `uint8_t` is a type alias for `unsigned char` and `char` types are rather special in that they can alias any other types. This method breaks strict aliasing and results in undefined behaviour when casting to any other type larger than `uint8_t`, e.g. when you cast `uint64_t` to `uint32_t*` or `uint16_t*`.

See [What is the Strict Aliasing Rule and Why do we care?](https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8) for more details.

Comment: Any particular reason for using `a * 0x100 + b` instead of `(a << 8) + b`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What would be the benefit of the latter?

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the byte order [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

As you can see this code determines the byte order in memory

```
uint16_t x = 0x0001; 
std::cout << (*((uint8_t*)&x) ? "little" : "big") << "-endian\n";
```

Try swapping numbers

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    uint16_t x = 0x0001;
    std::cout << (*((uint8_t*)&x) ? "little" : "big") << "-endian\n";

    uint8_t data[] = { 0x00, 0xFF };
    uint8_t* a = data;
    uint8_t* b = data + sizeof(uint8_t);
    uint16_t* ab = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(data);

    std::cout << std::hex << (int)*a << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)*b << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)*ab << "\n";
}
```

result

```
little-endian
0
ff
ff00
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case, it is better and easier to understand to use union and struct. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct mystruct {
      uint8_t a;
      uint8_t b;
    } ;
    union my_unino{
      mystruct x;
      uint16_t ab ;

    }data;

int main(){
  data.x.a=0x1;
  data.x.b=0xff;
  std::cout<<std::hex<<(int)data.x.a<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<std::hex<<data.ab<<std::endl;
  return 0;

}
```

Results:

```
1
ff01
```

Comment: However legal in C, this is UB in C++ (unless it changed for 17? Reference would be welcome), unless compiler extensions are used. Most mainstream compilers support union-based type punning so this might be fine for your use case, but you are risking non-portable code

Comment: It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written. [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)